# Preventing Symbols offset in map from being offset in legend of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer, legend, offset

I've been searching for a solution to this, but cannot seem to find an answer. I have a map where some stacked markers have been offset to be visible on the map. This makes their symbol offset in the layers panel, and subsequently in composer legends. I've played with spacing and other settings, but cannot get them to line up without removing the offset.

Is it possible to prevent symbols that have an offset applied in the map from having that offset displayed in the legend?

[image: Offset symbols]

Comment: Same here. It's really annoying. Legends look pretty ugly because of this.

Comment: Above solution works for the Layers panel as well as the "Legend panel" in print composer. But sorry to say: I realized that is has no effect on the legend in the print composer canvas and final printed map :-( (at least not in QGIS 3)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152952)

Comment: No I do not solve the problem - I wish I could as I have the same problem myself! But I point out, that the previous suggestion is not a solution, so I find my comment very relevant!

Answer (score 3):

If you use datadefined overrides for the "Anchor point", and all features are not anchored the same, this will (hopefully) leave the symbol in the center in your legend.
This is not a solution, only a work around. For now.
[image]

Comment: This works with lines too (QGIS 3.4 on OSX). For me, I gave it the datadefined override: "fid*0-3" to offset my lines by 3 mm. (Just using "-3" did not work.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple work around which involves printing the composer into a pdf and then editing the pdf (edit text and images). Align your symbols and then export the file as a JPG (or not if you prefer pdf).